# What are constrained genetic elements?

Tags: evolution, dna, sequence-analysis

I am somewhat of a newbie in evolutionary biology currently taking my first steps in bioinformatics. I was reading a paper when I came across the term  "constrained genetic elements", referring to sequences in the genome.

From what little I found googling the term, a constrained genetic element is a sequence/region in the genome that can be found preserved in many generations of a species. Is my understanding correct? What are the criteria by which those regions are identified?

The paper is [*Analysis and Classification of Constrained DNA Elements with N-gram Graphs and Genomic Signatures*](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-07953-0_18).

Comment: In what paper did you find the term? And in what context in the paper?

Comment: @kmm I added the paper title. The term is mentioned when explaining that classification is applied to "conserved sequences" in the genome, but no further explanation is given.